# Using WebClient to Download CSV File From SSRS Report

Tags: vb.net, csv, reporting-services, webclient

I'm trying to download a csv file from an SSRS report using the following code.

```
Const URI As String = "https://blah.blah.com/blah/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/blah/Production%20Reports/The_File.rdl&rs:format=csv"
Const DESTINATION As String = "C:\MyFile.csv"

Using myWebClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
    With myWebClient
        .Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
        .Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br")
        .Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
        .Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=%22The%5FFile.csv%22")
        .Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
        .Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/csv")
        .Headers.Add("Vary", "Accept-Encoding")
        .Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36")
        .Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
        .Headers.Add("Referer", URI)
        .Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "private")

        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("<my username>", "<my password>")
        .DownloadFile(URI, DESTINATION)
    End With
End Using
```

The problem is that the file that gets downloaded isn't a csv file.  When I open it in any text editor, all I see are "garbage" characters which seem like some sort of encoding is going on.  If I comment out the "Accept-Encoding" header and rerun the code, I get the code of the resulting HTML page - not the csv file I need.  Anyone know how I can download the file correctly?  BTW, I'm not sure all of the headers I added are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URI constant from this:

`Const URI As String = "https://blah.blah.com/blah/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/blah/Production%20Reports/The_File.rdl&rs:format=csv"`

To this:

`Const URI As String = "https://blah.blah.com/blah/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/blah/Production%20Reports/The_File.rdl&rs:format=csv&rs:Command=Render"`

You are missing the `Command=Render` part of the Uri.

Comment: I added the Command=Render part but I still get the HTML page response, not the csv file.

Comment: Have you tried this without all the additional Headers you are adding? Because, I run something similar to this each month, and I don't need to add all of that to get this to work.

Comment: I removed all of the Headers that I added (except for User-Agent -- that's required to avoid getting a 403 Forbidden error) and I still get the HTML page code, not the csv file.

Comment: Is WebDownload in a different version of the .NET Framework?  I'm using 4.5 and "WebDownload" isn't recognized.